# Python 2 Beginner

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to get to grips with the basics of Python, running basic functions and playing around with its capabilities, however, i am having some trouble understanding just how to invoke the other functions, below is an example of me playing around with functions, which function call would i write to invoke the other 3 and how would i write it? I know i must pass through string arguments also.

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
    return 140 * nights

def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city == "Charlotte":
        return 183
    elif city == "Tampa":
        return 220
    elif city == "Pittsburgh":
        return 222
    elif city == "Los Angeles":
        return 475

def rental_car_cost(days):
    total_car = days * 40
    if days >= 7:
       total_car -= 50
    elif days >= 3:
        total_car -= 20
    return total_car

def trip_cost(city, days):
    return rental_car_cost(days) + plane_ride_cost(city) + hotel_cost(days)
```

Comment: Does your trip_cost function already do what you are asking for? And wouldn't you just call trip_cost("berlin", 5)?

Comment: I'm confused what you're asking. It looks like you just need to call `trip_cost`. `trip_cost("Tampa", 2)`.

Comment: i had tried that so many times, it's only taken you to write it for me to realise its because i had put the number in quotation marks also hahaha, thankyou very much, i could have sworn i was going mad

Comment: @C.styan Np. And next time you post here, please be more direct about what your question is. If you had shown how your were trying to call it, and what the error you were getting was, it would have been much clearer what you were asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are a python beginner, I will explain a couple different ways you could invoke these functions. Let's assume that you have saved your python code in a file called 'trip.py'

**1. Add some invocation in 'trip.py'**

Add the following to trip.py, save the file and exit

```
total_cost = trip_cost('Los Angeles', 2) + trip_cost('Tampa', 3)
print('Two nights in LA and three in Tampa will cost ${}'.format(total_cost))
```

Execute the program from your shell:

```
python trip.py
Two nights in LA and three in Tampa will cost $1575
```

**2. Use trip.py as a module**

In the directory where you've saved 'trip.py', enter the interactive python interpreter by entering

```
python
```

at the command line. You'll know you've entered interactive mode when you see something like

```
>>>
```

import your trip module and invoke its methods.

```
>>> import trip
>>> total_cost = trip.trip_cost('Los Angeles', 2) + trip.trip_cost('Tampa', 3)
>>> print(total_cost)
1575
```

Or, to simplify, only import the necessary method(s)

```
>>> from trip import trip_cost
>>> total_cost = trip_cost('Los Angeles', 2) + trip_cost('Tampa', 3)
>>> print(total_cost)
1575
```

**Note**

There are many ways you could use the methods you have written. The most appropriate one will depend on your overall goal. In this case, it seems like you are just trying to get a feel for python and play around. For quick testing like this, I would suggest using the interactive python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
print trip_cost('Tampa', 3)

740
```

You have it correct, if your intention is for the fourth function to sum the output of the other three.

In this case, the first argument should be a string, the second argument should be an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined all of these methods, now all you have to do is call them and pass in the argument.  I defined a few variables at the top to illustrate the difference between passing strings to a function and passing variables.

```
city = ''
nights = 0    

def hotel_cost(nights):
    return 140 * nights

def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city == "Charlotte":
        return 183
    elif city == "Tampa":
        return 220
    elif city == "Pittsburgh":
        return 222
    elif city == "Los Angeles":
        return 475

def rental_car_cost(days):
    total_car = days * 40
    if days >= 7:
       total_car -= 50
    elif days >= 3:
        total_car -= 20
    return total_car

def trip_cost(city, days):
    return rental_car_cost(days) + plane_ride_cost(city) + hotel_cost(days)

trip_cost("Charlotte", 3)
```

If you run this, it will calculate 703, but you won't see any result.  You can see the result in the console with the print function.

```
print trip_cost("Charlotte", 3)
```

If you pass a string directly into a function, you must use quotes.  If you are passing in a variable, quotes are not used.  Quotes are also not used for integers.

Let's assign the same values to the variables we declared at the top, and pass them into our function.

```
city = "Charlotte"
nights = 3    

print trip_cost(city, nights)
```

That will print 703 as well.

You will rarely pass a hard-coded string into a function.  You will almost always be passing it a variable.

*Note: If you use Python 3, the print statement requires parentheses

```
print(trip_cost(city, nights))
```